# have the / a / --- / much/ many choice

Tags: meaning

What's the difference?

> 1 Do you have a choice?
>
> 2 Do you have the choice?
>
> 3 Do you have choice?
>
> 4 **Do you have much choice?**
>
> 5 **Do you have many choices?**

Comment: #4 is an extremely unlikely question. As [this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Do+you+have+much+choice%2CDo+you+have+any+choice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), the idiomatic standard here is *Do you have **any** choice?* Which is usually a rhetorical question anyway (speaker thinks the other person *doesn't* have any choice)...

Comment: ... But if the person who doesn't have options is describing the situation, the two possibilities *I don't have **much** choice* and *I don't have **any** choice* [are equally common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t+have+much+choice%2Cdon%27t+have+any+choice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and nearly always mean ***exactly*** the same thing. It's very unusual to say *I don't have **much** choice* with the intended sense of *I do have **some** choice, but **not much.***

Answer (score 1):

#1 and #2 mean much the same (the chance to choose between more than one alternative). *The choice* could refer to one particular choice - whether or not to do something.

#3 is not idiomatic.

#4 *I haven't much choice* can mean *I'm more or less forced to choose a particular alternative.*

#5 Are there many different alternatives for you to choose between?

Answer (score 1):

Most of these are valid (in the right context, of course), but mean slightly different things.

"Do you have a choice?" You are faced with some decision or something you must do. Is there only one possible option, or do you have multiple options? Often this means, in a realistic, practical sense. Like, "My doctor says I have to lose 50 pounds." In a literal sense, you have a choice: You could go on a diet, or not. But if not going on a diet means you will be dead within a year, you might say, "I have no choice."

"Do you have the choice?" Rare. It refers to some specific choice, as opposed to choice more generally.

"Do you have choice?" No. Choice is a singular noun and requires an article (or one of a few other words that can take the place of an article).

"Do you have much choice?" See my comment on #1. You could say, yes, technically I have a choice, I could do A or I could do B. But B is so obviously a bad idea that I really have to do A. I have a choice, but I don't have MUCH choice.

"Do you have many choices?" A choice is not always limited to two options. You could have many. Like, "I am trying to decide where to live when I retire. There are 20 places that all seem like good options, each with its own pros and cons. I have many choices." Versus, "No, I have to choose either A or B. I don't have many choices."

Answer (score 0):

#4 (Do you have much choice?) asks for a more general assessment of the flexibility of the situation.

#5 (Do you have many choices?) implies an explicit number of choices to be considered.

Both are grammatical and appropriate in writing and conversation.